# How to run azure bot in the bot framework emulator?

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I tried to test my azure bot using Bot framework emulator, but it is showing the following error

[image]

I have configured ngrok, still I'm not able to connect to the bot

[image]

Bot is working as expected in "Test in WebChat" in azure.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your Microsoft App ID and Microsoft App Password to the Emulator

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Ngrok is wrong.

I can see from your settings, that you *should* be pointed to an ngrok.exe, but check and make sure your ngrok is where it should be.

[image: Correctly tunneled emulator]

This is an image of me successfully tunneling to my deployed bot. Note that first three lines of the log to the right:

```
[08:32:12]Emulator listening on http://localhost:53057
[08:32:12]ngrok listening on https://71b4c689.ngrok.io
[08:32:12]ngrok traffic inspector:http://127.0.0.1:4040
[08:32:12]Will bypass ngrok for local addresses
```

When I go to my settings and remove the ngrok file (simulating my ngrok not being where it should be), I get your error exactly:

[image: incorrectly configured ngrok]

Double check your 'Path to Ngrok' in your settings.

[image: path to ngrok in settings]

Comment: "but check and make sure your ngrok is where it should be." where should I copy my ngrok.exe fille ?

Comment: So my 'ngrok.exe' file is in a folder on my desktop called 'ngrok'. I used the 'browse' button in that last picture to navigate to the folder (C:\Users\v-jewail\Desktop\ngrok) and then selected my ngrok.exe file. You might be only pointing to the folder, instead of the .exe file. The full path (for me) in 'path to ngrok' is 'C:\Users\v-jewail\Desktop\ngrok\ngrok.exe'

Comment: my path is also pointing to ngrok.exe itself. Is there anything else I should do while connecting deployed bot ? Like running solution in visual studio or anything else ?

Comment: No, if the code is deployed and works when you hit 'test in webchat' on the azure portal, there is no solution to run. It's already *running*. Maybe delete your ngrok.exe and download a new one? It might need to be updated.